# Помогите с mySQL Update

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysqli

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста с запросом:

```
UPDATE page SET `next_visit` = IF(`last_visite` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `cdate`, `last_visite`) + INTERVAL ROUND(1440/MAX(IF(IF(`quantity` = 0, 1, `quantity`)*95/100/30>0.01, IF(`quantity` = 0, 1, `quantity`)*95/100/30,  0.01))*rand()) MINUTE WHERE id = 1;
```

Где может быть ошибка?
Таблицы `next_visit, last_visite, cdate` - timestamp
`Update` не делает говорит что `#1111 - Неправильное использование групповых функций`

Как мне его завести?

Если так то работает

```
SELECT IF(`last_visite` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', `cdate`, `last_visite`) + INTERVAL ROUND(1440/MAX(IF(IF(`quantity` = 0, 1, `quantity`)*100/100/30>0.01, IF(`quantity` = 0, 1, `quantity`)*100/100/30, 0.01))*rand()) MINUTE as next_V, `cdate` FROM `page` WHERE `id` = 1;
```

Comment: Ты при селекте выбираешь два значения, и пытаешься тоже самое сделать в апдейте......надо выбрать что-то одно, либо `IF(\`last_visite\` = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', \`cdate\`, \`last_visite\`) + INTERVAL ROUND(1440/MAX(IF(IF(\`quantity\` = 0, 1, \`quantity\`)*95/100/30>0.01`  .......... либо `IF(\`quantity\` = 0, 1, \`quantity\`)*95/100/30,  0.01))*rand()) MINUTE`